# get parameters from the request body along with a model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

how to get the devId from the body, even using [FromBody], it keeps identifying the devId as a query

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Module>> PostModule([FromBody]Module module, long devId){}
```

Comment: You put FromBody in front of module, so if devId is also in the Body then it must be part of the Module class and not an individual parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have 1  argument with a `FromBody` applied.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#frombody-attribute-1)

> Don't apply `[FromBody]` to more than one parameter per action method. Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other `[FromBody]` parameters.

If you want that `devId` being read from the body, you'll have to include that one as e.g. a property in your `Module` class.

Comment: there is no way to get this parameter from the body without including it in the class?

Comment: No since the body can only be read once, which happens on model binding of that `Module` argument.